# Have I proven P equals NP if I find an amortized O(n) algorithm for Subset Sum

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, subset-sum

I have found an algorithm that runs quite fast on Subset Sum problem few years ago (sometime around 2016). It basically sorts the input set in descending order (instead of the regular ascending) and does the backtracking then to arrive at results. It solves a 1,000,000 instance set in 5 minutes on my i5 8 GB RAM machine!

This year I stumbled upon this github repo:
[GitHub Link for Subset Sum](https://github.com/parthnan/SubsetSum-BacktrackAlgorithm)

by another user, who claims to have solved it in amortized O(n) complexity as per his detailed analysis available on the repo. Does this prove P=NP as well, as maybe amortized O(n) implies polynomial complexity for the problem?

P.S. that I have come across many fast Subset Sum problems but I am just curious in this specific case as it relates to my algorithm too.

Comment: Amortized complexity is defined for a sequence of operations. Can you elaborate on what is the sequence of operations here?

Comment: Subset-sum is known for having many easy instances and some hard instances, so a solver that can solve some instances very rapidly is not impressive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not what amortized analysis means: you can not infer the worst case runtime of an algorithm by plotting the actual execution time on larger and larger instances of some specific structure. Sadly, that doesn't prove you have a polynomial-time algorithm. Even when you want to do experimental work, there are other parameters to vary besides the size of the input that will have a major impact on the runtime of the proposed solution. If you do so, you will have a result that roughly says "here's an algorithm that performs well in practice for instances that look like this, but I can't give any theoretical guarantees".

To summarize, it's not impressive to have an algorithm which solves huge instances belonging to a specific family of instances of an NP-hard problem quickly. What is impressive (or rather extremely remarkable), is to have an algorithm that you can prove runs in time that is polynomial in the size of the input regardless of the structure of the instance.

Answer (score 2):

Subset-sum illustrates the importance of input encoding in defining NP-complete problems.

Subset-sum for $n$ integers in $[1,k]$ can be solved in $O(nk)$ worst-case time. That's a linear algorithm if the input is encoded in unary. But the problem is NP-complete if you encode the integers in binary, which takes $O(n\log k)$ bits.

The GitHub code that you linked defines the problem it solves as

> From a set of N numbers from 1 to 1,000,000, find a subset that sums up to a random number X (1,000,000 < X < N×1,000,000).

I don't know whether the code in the repo actually solves this in worst-case $O(n)$ time, but it's known to be possible to do so, even though subset-sum is NP-complete.

It's also possible to encode the input in $O(k\log n)$ bits by listing the multiplicity of each integer. For fixed $k$, $O(n)$ is exponential time if you use that encoding.